# PyQt4 & SQLITE data retrievement

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt4

This is my sql initialization.

```
self.data = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
self.data.setDatabaseName('new_ship')
self.data.open()
self.sql_model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
self.sql_model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
self.first_date= '2015-01-01'
self.second_date = '2015-01-01'
self.sql_model.setTable('new_ship')
query = QtSql.QSqlQuery("SELECT submit_date FROM new_ship WHERE submit_date BETWEEN "+"'"+self.first_date+"'"+' AND '+"'"+self.second_date+"'")
self.sql_model.setQuery(query)
self.sql_model.select()
self.tableView.setModel(self.sql_model)
self.tableView.show()
self.data.close()
```

i would like to get the  date range from my db according to my submitted query.
The result that i keep getting is :
please visit the list below ( i cant post imgs)

http://postimg.org/image/s2iod1vs1/

while my desired result would be only : 2015-01-01

I check the query using my sqlite browser and everything looks fine :

Help is needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the format operator on your SQL query string:

```
query = QtSql.QSqlQuery("SELECT submit_date FROM new_ship WHERE submit_date 
BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}'".format(self.first_date, self.second_date))
```

Comment: Hi Parfair, Thanks for replying . i tried your suggestion and still keep getting the same result .

Comment: Consider rewriting your query execution using this [SQL Model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-model.html) link. You set up a table model but then define a query model then use tableView. I am not familiar with the QtSQL module, but it may be only your table new_ship is being outputted. Try executing the query with [query.exec(SQL str)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-sqlstatements.html).